# Finding records in column A that match 3 out of 4 records in column B SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Above is sample data illustrating my question.
What I am trying to achieve is to find all the products in column A that are stored in warehouses BB, CC, and so on but are missing in AA which is a master warehouse. To determine which products need to be added to the master warehouse.
I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: What is it you need help with? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work? What is your question here?

Comment: My question is how can this be achieved?
I seem to have run into a wall and cannot think of a way to achieve the result presented in a smaller table.

Comment: How can *what* be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `not exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT fruits
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  NOT EXSITS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.fruits = b.fruits AND
                          b.warehouse = 'AA')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a query like below will help

```
select distinct fruits 
from yourtable T
where warehouse <> 'AA' 
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from yourtable YT 
    where YT.warehouse = 'AA' and YT.fruits = T.fruits
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the fruit that is missing, you can use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select fruit
from t
group by fruit
having sum(case when warehouse = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you want the complete rows, then `not exists` is one approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.fruit = t.fruit and t2.warehouse = 'AA'
                 );
```